# On which C standard will C++14 be based?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer, c++14

Which revision of the C standard serves as the basis for C++14?

C++11 is based on C99 and was released a few months before C11. Will C++14 be based on C11? The [current draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) still (as of Dec 2013) seems to say "based on ISO/IEC 9899:1999", i.e. C99, and I heard repeatedly that C++14 is "nearly complete" and only undergoing minor tweaks at this point. Is it plausible that the dependency on C will be revised before the new standard goes to the vote?

Comment: Not even close to definite, but [N3538](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3538.html) speaks of adding C11's restrict as an option to solve aliasing, I suspect if it were to be rebased, that would not be an optional solution.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yeah, `restrict` is a sore point... I've heard C++ experts complain that it's rather ill-defined even within C99, and it's unlikely to make it into C++ any time soon. I'd be more interested in, say, whether the memory model of both languages can be kept in sync.

Comment: @KerrekSB: but the memory model of C++11 isn't defined just by reference to C99 anyway, because of the co-operation with C11 over threads. So I'd say yes, the memory model of both can be kept in sync. Regardless of what version of C is referenced.

Comment: We don't want type-generic macros or other C11 features in C++, so it would be a bad idea to rebase on C11. We might want some of the new library features of future C standards, but C++14 references C99 not the current C standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That's a shame - sounds like a growing schism? Can you make that reasoning into an answer?

Answer (score 13):

At least in the current Draft of the C++ Standard there is written that its normative documents include

> — ISO/IEC 9899:1999, Programming languages — C
>
> — ISO/IEC
> 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001(E), Programming languages — C, Technical
> Corrigendum 1
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2004(E), Programming languages
> — C, Technical Corrigendum 2
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E),
> Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 3

So it looks like the new C++ Standard will be based on C99.